# Solr uses too much memory

Tags: memory-leaks, solr, jvm, mmap

We have a Solr 3.4 instance running on Windows 2008 R2 with Oracle Java 6 Hotspot JDK that becomes unresponsive.  When we looked at the machine, we noticed that the available physical memory went to zero.

The Tomcat7.exe process was using ~70Gigs (Private Working Set) but Working Set (Memory) was using all the memory on the system.  There were no errors in the Tomcat / Solr logs.  We used VMMap to identify that the memory was being used for memory mapping the Solr segement files.

Restarting Tomcat fixed the problem temporarily, but it eventually came back.

We then tried decreasing the JVM size to give more space for the memory mapped files, but then the Solr eventually becomes unresponsive with the old generation at 100%.  Again resetting fixed the problem, but it did not throw an out-of-memory exception before we reset.

Currently our spidey sense is telling us that the cache doesn't shrink when there is memory pressure, and that maybe there are too many MappedByteBuffers hanging around so that the OS can not free up the memory from memory mapped files.

Comment: Are you using content extraction with Tika/Solr Cell or using some kind of sorting on the queries?

Comment: Curious as to which JVM version you were using. 6u17 and earlier have several nasty JIT and GC issues.

Comment: what kind of data are you indexing?

Answer (score 1):

There are too many parameters and too little information to help with any details. This answer is also quite old as are the mentioned systems.

Here are some things that helped in my experience:

- rather decrease RAM usage in Tomcat as well as in SOLR to decrease the risk of swapping. Leave the system space to breath.
- if this "starts" to appear without any changes to Tomcat or the SOLR config - than maybe it is due to the fact that the amount of data that SOLR has to index and query has increased. This can either mean that the original config was never good to begin with or that the limit of the current resources have been reached and have to be reviewed. Which one is it?
- check the queries (if you can influence them): move any subquery constructs that are often requested into filterqueries, move very individual request constructs into the regular query parameter. Decrease query cache, increase/keep filter query cache - or decrease filter cache in case filter queries aren't used that much in your system.
- check the schema.xml of SOLR on configuration errors (could just be misconceptions really). I ran into this once: while importing fields would be created en masse causing the RAM to overflow.
- if it happens during import: check whether the import process is set to autocommit and commits rather often and does also optimize - maybe it is possible to commit less often and optimize only once at the end.
- upgrade Java, Tomcat and SOLR

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the new default policy SOLR uses for directories (it tries to map them to RAM or something like that).

Read this:
http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/11789qq3nm/virtual-memory-usage-increases-beyond-xmx-with-solr-3-3