# SOLR uses too much memory (part 2)

Tags: java, spring, solr, lucene

This is basically the same as this question, but there were no useful answers and the situation is slightly different:

[Solr uses too much memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894687/solr-uses-too-much-memory?s=1|4.2754)

We're running SOLR 5.5.0 on Windows 2008 R2 with JDK version 1.8.0_77-b03.  When running our indexing process, The java process running SOLR has a private working set that ends up using all 8 GB of memory on the box.

We're indexing 3M+ documents using a Spring Batch Starter process we wrote using the SOLRJ client.  This is the code that indexes the documents we've collected:

```
    log.info("Adding " + docList.size() + " documents to Solr index");
    if(docList.size() == 0) {
        log.warn("Was asked to index 0 records, but input size was " + items.size());
    } else {
        log.debug("Splitting list of size " + docList.size() + " into manageable chunks of " + batchCommitSize);
        List<List<SolrInputDocument>> partitionedList = Lists.partition(docList, batchCommitSize);

        SolrClient solrClient = (SolrClient) applicationContext.getBean("solrClient");

        for (List<SolrInputDocument> chewableChunk : partitionedList) {
            solrClient.add(chewableChunk);
            solrClient.commit();
            log.info(chewableChunk.size() + " documents committed.");
        }

        log.info("Finished batch indexing of " + docList.size() + " documents.");
    }
```

The Spring configuration for the SOLRJ client:

```
@Value("${code.search.num.solr.threads}")
private int numSolrThreads;

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient solrClient() {
    return new ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient(solrHost, 100, numSolrThreads);
}

//code.search.num.solr.threads=25
```

Here's our schema definition.  It's really long, so I just cut and paste the part with our field definitions.  I can upload more if necessary.  Most of it was copied from the sample configuration in the tutorial.

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="*" dest="_text_"/>

<field name="fileName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="projectName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="lastCommitAuthor" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="vcsUrl" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="teamCityUrl" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="jenkinsUrl" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="relativePath" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

<!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness.
  Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
-->
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

The previous question indicated that memory mapped files might be the culprit, but we've been unable to find a way to turn that off.  We also tried closing and recreating the client on every commit,

Is there any way that we can reduce the amount of memory SOLR uses while indexing?

Comment: How much memory do you allocate for your Solr process?

Comment: 4GB.  Memory options are `-XX:+UseG1GC ^
  -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 ^
  -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
  -XX:+AggressiveHeap`

Answer (score 2):

I know how to turn `mmapcache` off.  In `solrConfig.xml` search for `directoryFactory` and replace the existing tag with the given below.

This will turn off Mmapped files:

```
<directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory"
class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.SimpleFSDirectoryFactory.}"/>
```

Due to this change you will not be able to get near real time search.